# expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener with Firestore callback inside: conditionally return true/false

Tags: android, firebase, callback, google-cloud-firestore, expandablelistview

So here's my situation. I have an expandableListview with an onChildClickListener attached and inside I have a Firestore callback which is suppose to get data from my database.  The problem I'm trying to solve (because of Firestore's asynchronous behavior) is how to do a conditional return for the clickListener depending on what returns from the callback.

Code:

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            firebaseGetThisThing.readData(new FirebaseGetThisThing.FirestoreCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCallback(Thing thing, String documentID) {
                    if (thing != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "This thing: " + thing.toString());
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Nothing found.");
                    }
                }
            });
            return false; <---need this return to be conditional true/false
        }
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You won't be able return from your click handler with any knowledge of an asynchronous method that was started within it.  You'll have to find another way to achieve your intended effect (which you haven't mentioned in your question at all).

Comment: Sorry.  I need to control whether the click event fires.  If the user clicks on the onChildClick and the returned value is true then block the event from happening (return true).  If it's not then return false (allow the click event to fire.

Comment: Then you'll have to query for everything you need *before* you allow clicks on views that need this information.

Comment: Good point.  I'm actually already using the callback in my MainActivity which calls the adapter, so maybe I'll pass the results through the adapter.  I'll give that a shot and report back.  Thanks!